# Spring Transaction Rollback When No SQL is Executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am wondering if I need to rollback the following if the **orderId** is null, and the following SQL statement is never run?  This is a simplified example of a method that is somewhat larger.

I am wondering if starting a transaction, but not doing anything due to the orderId being null, should be terminated somehow.

```
public OrderInfo insertOrder(String orderId) throws OrderException {
    OrderInfo orderInfo = null;
    DefaultTransactionDefinition txnDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    txnDefinition.setName("InsertOrder");
    txnDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    TransactionStatus txnStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(txnDefinition);

    if (orderId != null && !orderId.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            orderInfo = orderDao.insertOrder(orderId);

            if (orderInfo != null && orderInfo.getOrderId() > 0) {
                transactionManager.commit(txnStatus);
            }
            else {
                transactionManager.rollback(txnStatus);
                throw new OrderException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transactionManager.rollback(txnStatus);
            throw new OrderException();
        }
    }

// else rollback?

    return orderInfo;
}
```

Comment: "transaction rollback" when you are not making any transaction in its real sense, why do we need to rollback, or what state exists to rollback? My answer is No

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try Spring `TransactionTemplate`

```
    TransactionTemplate tt = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager, transactionDefinition);
    OrderInfo orderInfo = tt.execute(new TransactionCallback<OrderInfo>() {
        @Override
        public T doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            return orderDao.insertOrder(orderId);
        }
    });
```

this is a guarantee that all things will be done right